# Delay In JMeter

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I am using `JMeter` for tasting a site. I am creating a `GET` request to an `URL` which returns a `html` document. From that document I am extracting a value using `XPath Extractor` which is the `key` of next request `URL` I am going to make. 
The problem is, for single user its working fine, but for multiple users sometimes it fails to extract because of getting partial(not full) `html` as response.

How can I make the extractor to delay a bit before starting to extract the key or Is there any other way to get the entire html document before starting extraction?

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, partial response indicates a problem and setting a delay is not what you should be looking for as XPath Extractor is a **Post Processor** hence response data will remain the same no matter for now long you will be sleeping before XPath Extractor fires.

Few things to consider:

1. All post processors and assertions have their cost and XPath Extractor is the most "expensive" one as it builds DOM in memory. In case of large responses and severe loads it's behavior may be flaky. Try switching to [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
2. Make sure that JMeter has enough memory allocated. For Windows look for `set HEAP=-Xms512m -Xmx512m` line in *jmeter.bat* file and increase max heap value (Xmx) to be approx 75% of available RAM.
3. If you're running tests using JMeter GUI - consider switching to command-line, Ant, Maven or whatever mode. See [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for options available
4. Make sure that you're following recommendations from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/) post.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used the `css/jQuery Extractor` but still facing the same problem though the performance is improved..What can be wrong now??

Comment: It might indicate a problem on server side. It worth checking logs and hardware metrics like CPU/RAM/Disk/Network, etc. It can be done either manually or using PerfMon plugin - http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/. By the way, what is your Latency metric?

Comment: Found the problem..its in the `webService` application is calling. .I have tested the service by `SOAP/XML-RPC Request`. Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Use "Constant timer"

right click on your HTTP request --> Timer --> Constant Timer

hope this will help.

Comment: how much value did you put for delay?

Comment: thats 1 Second... keep it as 5000ms ... if it still fails then the issue is probably somewhere else.